# TCP Socket: How to use FD_ISSET() on server to detect client's sending data?

Tags: tcp, unix-socket

I have a server which has several sockets connected with counterpart clients, I want to use select() to detect whether a client is sending data to the counterpart socket. My code is:

```
fd_set player_fd_set;
  FD_ZERO(&player_fd_set);
  int max_fd = players[0].connected_socket_on_master;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
    FD_SET(players[i].connected_socket_on_master, &player_fd_set);
    if (players[i].connected_socket_on_master > max_fd) {
      max_fd = players[i].connected_socket_on_master;
    }
  }

  select(max_fd + 1, &player_fd_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
    printf("Check fd # %d\n", i);
    if (FD_ISSET(players[i].connected_socket_on_master, &player_fd_set)) {
      printf("Coming from player # %d\n", i);
      ssize_t recvStatus = recv(players[i].connected_socket_on_master,
                                potato.trace, sizeof(potato.trace), 0);
      if (recvStatus == -1) {
        printf("Error: Could not recv final potato from player # %d\n", i);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

It seems that FD_ISSET() returns immediately after first time entering the for-loop. I read from other question in stackoverflow that select() is level-triggered instead of edge-triggered, then how could I detect the data received from a socket?

Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to put this whole bunch of code in a while(1) loop? Because I find many code are doing so.

Comment: Yes, you need to call `select()` in a loop for the lifetime of the server, resetting `player_fd_set` on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fd_set` setup is fine, but you are not checking the return value of `select()` for `> 0` before entering the reading loop.

Your reading loop is calling `break` in the wrong place, in fact it should not be calling `break` *at all*.  You are exiting the loop as soon as *any* client sends data, ignoring *other* clients which may *also* have sent data that is waiting to be read.  You need to loop through the entire `fd_set` reading from every socket that is in a readable state.

Your reading loop should not be calling `exit()` if `recv()` fails. Just `close()` the failed socket, remove that socket from `players[]`, and move on to the next loop iteration.

If `recv()` returns -1, be sure to check `errno` for `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN`, as they are not fatal errors.  Also, if `recv()` returns 0, the client has disconnected.

Try something more like this:

```
fd_set player_fd_set;
FD_ZERO(&player_fd_set);

int max_fd = players[0].connected_socket_on_master;
for (int i = 0; i < num_players; ++i)
{
    FD_SET(players[i].connected_socket_on_master, &player_fd_set);
    if (players[i].connected_socket_on_master > max_fd)
        max_fd = players[i].connected_socket_on_master;
}

if (select(max_fd + 1, &player_fd_set, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0)
{
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; ++i)
    {
        printf("Check fd # %d\n", i);

        if (!FD_ISSET(players[offset].connected_socket_on_master, &player_fd_set))
            continue;

        printf("Coming from player # %d\n", i);

        ssize_t recvStatus = recv(players[offset].connected_socket_on_master, potato.trace, sizeof(potato.trace), 0);
        if (recvStatus > 0)
        {
            // process potato.trace up to recvStatus bytes as needed...
            ++offset;
            continue;
        }

        if (recvStatus < 0)
        {
            if ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN))
            {
                // no more data to read right now...
                ++offset;
                continue;
            }

            printf("Error: Could not recv final potato from player # %d\n", i);
        }
        else
            printf("Player # %d disconnected\n", i);

        close(players[offset].connected_socket_on_master);

        for(int j = i+1; j < num_players; ++j)
            players[j-1] = players[j];

        --num_players;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's really a guide-like answer!